# Using .str.contains with pandas dataframe to check values in a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to check the values in a column against a list of strings in a list.
If anything in the column matches any of the strings in the list, then perform action.

Dataframe in question:

```
        Date              Description        Category  Amount
5 2020-05-23  CAPITAL ONE ONLINE PYMT  Payment/Credit -200.00
4 2020-05-25               Amazon.com     Merchandise   73.78
3 2020-05-26             AMZN Mktp US     Merchandise   14.88
1 2020-05-27           DOMINO'S PIZZA          Dining   17.42
2 2020-05-27            SALEM REC CTR     Health Care   20.89
0 2020-05-28      JAPANESE RESTAURANT          Dining   31.69
```

Code in question:

```
# Define the Description reference list for the Misc Category
misc_ref_list = ['Amazon', 'AMZN']

if in_df['Description'].str.contains("|".join(misc_ref_list)) == True:
    in_df['Category'] = 'Misc'
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
    if in_df['Description'].str.contains("|".join(misc_ref_list), flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True) == True:      
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1538, in __nonzero__
    f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense for python to check if a list of boolean is True or not:

```
>>> in_df['Description'].str.contains("|".join(misc_ref_list))
5    False
4     True
3     True
1    False
2    False
0    False
Name: Description, dtype: bool
```

The Series is True or False? It's ambiguous. So what you need is boolean indexing:

```
mask = in_df['Description'].str.contains("|".join(misc_ref_list))
df.loc[mask, 'Category'] = 'Misc'
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         Date              Description        Category  Amount
5  2020-05-23  CAPITAL ONE ONLINE PYMT  Payment/Credit -200.00
4  2020-05-25               Amazon.com            Misc   73.78
3  2020-05-26             AMZN Mktp US            Misc   14.88
1  2020-05-27           DOMINO'S PIZZA          Dining   17.42
2  2020-05-27            SALEM REC CTR     Health Care   20.89
0  2020-05-28      JAPANESE RESTAURANT          Dining   31.69
```